# is there a way to keep on the same idea without using the index()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
            'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

message = ["a", "d"]
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

w = len(message)
z = len(alphabet)
for i in range(w):
    letter = message[i]
    for x in range(z):
        if letter == alphabet[x]:
            for g in range(x, z):
                letter = alphabet[shift]

    print(f" the final {letter}")
```

For example the shift is = 1 then a should become b and d should become e but I don't now why the print function at the end prints the letter for both a and d the value b

I was expecting to get at the end if the shift = 1

```
 the final b
 the final e
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Why do you need the `for g` loop? Just use `letter = alphabet[(x+shift) % z]`

Comment: `letter = alphabet[shift]` will always assign the same position (shift) in the alphabet.  you probably meant to use a different variable for that index.

Comment: @Swifty but the title says they don't want to use `.index()`

Comment: @Barmar: once more, oups :) I should read more carefully!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `str.translate` method.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
t = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]))

shift = 3
message = "ad"

# outputs "ad -> dg" 
print(f'{message} -> {message.translate(t)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code simpler using enumerate instead of iterating over indexes.   A simple way to keep the same approach (sequential search) is to prepare a shifted alphabet list beforehand and use the original letter indexes as positions for the replacement letters in the shifted list

```
message = ["a", "d"]
shift   = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

shifted = alphabet[shift:]+alphabet[:shift]  # shifted alphabet
   
for i,letter in enumerate(message):      # each letter and position in message
    for j,alpha in enumerate(alphabet):  # find position in alphabet
        if alpha == letter:              # when match found 
            message[i] = shifted[j]      # replace letter in message


print(message) # ['b', 'e'] with a shift of 1
```

A more advanced technique would be to use the internal letter numbers to directly compute the character number of the replacement letter (97 is the internal number for 'a').

```
message = ["a", "d"]
shift   = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

message = [chr((ord(c)-97+shift)%26+97) for c in message]
```